# move Arc drawn using CGContextAddArc iOS Objective c

Tags: ios, xcode, cgcontext, uitouch

I have drawn an arc using below code,

```
CGPoint circleCenter = CGPointMake(self.bounds.size.width / 2, self.bounds.size.height / 2);

CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 20.0);

CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context,[UIColor redColor].CGColor);

CGContextAddArc(context, circleCenter.x , circleCenter.y, 100, [self radians:315], [self radians:135], 1);

CGContextStrokePath(context);
```

now i  need to  know can i move this arc in circular path using below method.?

```
- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet<UITouch *> *)touches withEvent:(nullable UIEvent *)event
```

If not how can i program an arc shape which can be moved using above method.?